# @Types/Sequelize Error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in ambient context

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, sequelize.js, tsc

I have a project that shows this error when I run 'tsc':

```
../modules/node_modules/sequelize/types/lib/transaction.d.ts:33:14 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

33   static get LOCK(): LOCK;
                ~~~~

../modules/node_modules/sequelize/types/lib/transaction.d.ts:40:7 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

40   get LOCK(): LOCK;
         ~~~~
```

My versions are:

- "@types/sequelize": "^4.28.6"
- "sequelize": "^5.8.10"
- "sequelize-typescript": "1.0.0-beta.4"

The project works fine with nodemon but fails when I try to compile the typescript. Anyone knows this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you need to use typescript 3.7.

[from typescript 3.7 release notes:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html)

```
To detect the issue around accessors, TypeScript 3.7 will now emit get/set accessors in .d.ts files so that in TypeScript can check for overridden accessors.
```

so presumably `sequelize` was compiled with typescript 3.7 and emits definition files that previous versions don't understand. So you'll need to upgrade to typescript 3.7 or use an earlier version of sequelize.

Comment: What if I can't upgrade to 3.7? have another idea?

Comment: @ShlomiLevi Use an earlier version of `@types/sequelize`

Comment: you are right, I had this issue recently and after some searches I discoreved an issue closed in the Github, so to fix the problem I had to upgrade the typescript version to the 3.7.2 version.

Comment: ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.1.1 and <3.2.0 but 3.7.4 was found instead. Im using Angular 7

Answer (score 41):

I have **Angular 8**. it is working with typescript version of 3.4.5. so solve this issue do below steps.

step 1) go to the **tsconfig.json** file

step 2) add **skipLibCheck: true** in "compilerOptions" object. It works for me.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist-debug/",
    "skipLibCheck": true, /// Needs to be true to fix wrong alias types being used

  },
```

Comment: Thanks. "skipLibCheck": true(added to tsconfig that related to NestJs), worked and NestJs with app that inited through nest g ng-app.

Comment: This was a better solution than upgrading our Typescript version. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Setting `"skipLibCheck": true` worked for me.

Comment: In which file I need to change this?

Comment: tsconfig.json file