# Three JS + Angular 7 getting error BufferAttribute after imported to controller

Tags: angular, typescript, three.js, babeljs

I am using Angular 7 and I want to add [Three JS](https://threejs.org/) to my project. But I'm getting an error after I imported it to my component controller. I did install  `npm install three --save` and their type `npm install @type/webgl2`. It shows error in my terminal VS code and code doesn't work either. I not quite sure that I am made it correctly, but what I import is `import * as THREE from 'three';`. I've been following one [document](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-playground-j1yzza?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) on Stackblitz and it working but still have an error shows that makes me cannot build my project. Any way to get rid of these errors? 
This is what my error looks like:

```
ERROR in node_modules/three/src/core/BufferAttribute.d.ts(21,6): error 
TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/three/src/core/InterleavedBufferAttribute.d.ts(19,6): error 
TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/three/src/core/InterleavedBufferAttribute.d.ts(20,6): error 
TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message that you are getting?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my questions.

Comment: Maybe this might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802463/types-sequelize-error-ts1086-an-accessor-cannot-be-declared-in-ambient-context

Comment: Could you accept the answer ?

Answer (score 3):

Install this **devDependencies**

```
npm install --save-dev @types/offscreencanvas
npm install --save-dev @types/webgl2
```

Update your **tsconfig.app.json**

```
 "types": ["node", "webgl2", "offscreencanvas"]
```

#### `package.json` looks like this.

```
{
  "name": "sketch",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "subsink": "^1.0.0",
    "three": "^0.110.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.20",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.20",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/offscreencanvas": "^2019.6.0",
    "@types/webgl2": "0.0.5",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

#### `tsconfig.app.json` looks like this.

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node", "webgl2", "offscreencanvas"]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: this solution not working in my case, i am using angular 8 and angular 8 support typescript <v3.5

Comment: Look at the types

Comment: i have installed types and included in tsconfig.app.json, but dint work

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the

> "three": "^0.110.0"

Answer (score 2):

For **Angular 8** we can do
As Omar Arturo said we can downgrade **threejs** to **0.110.0** but does not work out of the box we have to

```
npm install @types/webgl2
```

and **tsconfig.app.json**

```
"types": ["node", "webgl2", "offscreencanvas"]
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is solved in latest Three r115. Works out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do two things. Also, make sure that you installed the following modules,

**Step 01 :**
Install devDependencies

```
npm install --save-dev @types/offscreencanvas
```

then update **tsconfig.app.json**

```
"types": ["node", "webgl2"]
```

**Step 02 :**
Go to the tsconfig.json file and add **skipLibCheck: true** in **"compilerOptions"** object.
eg:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    ...
    "skipLibCheck": true, 
  },
```

For more: this error happens because of the typescript version issue. So you can fix this by skipping lib check. In fact, some others facing that WebGL issue. So if you are using three.js then these solutions will solve your problem.