# How to solve conflict between sequelize and angular in lerna monorepo with typescript?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, lerna, monorepo

I have monorepo with lerna. in my project I have nodejs and angular.

Angular uses `"typescript": "~3.5.3"`.

Nodejs have those packages to work with sequelize:

```
"@types/node": "^12.12.16",
"@types/validator": "^12.0.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
"sequelize": "^5.21.2",
"sequelize-typescript": "^1.1.0"
```

The problem is I got error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ..\..\node_modules\sequelize\types\lib\transaction.d.ts:33:14
    TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
```

According to [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802463/types-sequelize-error-ts1086-an-accessor-cannot-be-declared-in-ambient-context) I need to upgrade to 3.7.3. When I upgrade it works fine in nodejs sequelize side.

But when I change the typescript to 3.7.3 then angular doesn't work:

```
ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.6.0 but 3.7.3 was found instead.
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: if I can't upgrade typescript in angular, then can I run sequelize-typescript in 3.5.3 anyway?

Comment: What vesion of Node.js & Angular are you using?

Comment: you mean typescript version? or angular( "@angular/core": "~8.2.11") version? nodejs doesn't have a version, it's just typescript files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.5.0 but 3.5.3 was found instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216110/the-angular-compiler-requires-typescript-3-4-0-and-3-5-0-but-3-5-3-was-found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can fix this error for you, but you should separate your projects because it's difficult to maintain a front-end and back-end monorepo. This won't be your last conflict of dependencies.

Angular 8.x is stuck on TypeScript 3.5, but everything I've read online says it will compile *okay* with the latest TypeScript 3.7, and Angular 9 is reportedly going to target 3.7 as well because of Ivy.

You have to disable enforcing of the TypeScript version by the Angular compiler:

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  // ...
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "disableTypeScriptVersionCheck": true
  }
}
```

That will get the project to compile, but you'll get a run-time error because Angular 8 doesn't define a default importer. We can fix this by adding one to the polyfills

**polyfills.ts**:

```js
// @ts-ignore
window.__importDefault = function(mod) {
  return mod && mod.__esModule ? mod : { default: mod };
};
```

Later when you upgrade to Angular 9. The above can be undone and it should compile with TypeScript 3.7