# While upgrade the latest angular slickgrid version facing build issue

Tags: angular, typescript, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

I was using angular slickgrid version 2.19.0. After upgrading to the latest angular slickgrid version 2.29.1,  facing build issue (ng build).

Here is the error screenshot

[image: Error Screenshot]

Software versions

- Angular: 7.3.5
- TypeScript: 3.1.6
- Node: 10.16.3
- NPM: 6.9.0

Comment: did my answer posted below resolved your issue? If so you should accept the answer to tell others that the question was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Note that I'm the author of Angular-Slickgrid.

That's a TypeScript issue unrelated to the lib, or at least partially, because your Angular and TypeScript versions are way too old and are also tagged as EOL (end of life) so they are basically no longer supported, perhaps it's time for you to upgrade. I believe you need at least TypeScript `3.6.0` (or `3.7.0` I'm not sure) to get rid of this issue as posted and answered on this other SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61280304/1212166) with Angular on the Stack Overflow question [TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in ambient context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60092642/ts1086-an-accessor-cannot-be-declared-in-ambient-context). If you can't upgrade, then you'll have to stick with an older version of everything and not enjoy any of the fixes and new features... The main problem is that TypeScript changed the Type `d.ts` files structure around TypeScript version `3.6.0+`

... again it might be time for you to upgrade, even Node 10 is EOL

At the current time the lowest supported version of Angular is 9 (LTS ends on "Aug 6, 2021"), if you upgrade to that version or higher (probably better higher since it ends very soon), then that will fix your issue.