# Angular Can't use datepicker

Tags: angular

I'm trying to using date-picker and it error as below

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/configurable-focus-trap.d.ts(24,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/configurable-focus-trap.d.ts(25,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts(32,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts(33,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts(140,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts(141,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts(146,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts(147,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/key-manager/list-key-manager.d.ts(96,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/key-manager/list-key-manager.d.ts(98,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/live-announcer/live-announcer.d.ts(69,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/live-announcer/live-announcer.d.ts(70,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/bidi/dir.d.ts(26,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/bidi/dir.d.ts(27,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/bidi/dir.d.ts(29,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/collections/selection-model.d.ts(24,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/observe-content.d.ts(62,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/observe-content.d.ts(63,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/observe-content.d.ts(66,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/observe-content.d.ts(67,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts(60,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts(61,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts(63,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts(64,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts(86,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts(87,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts(89,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts(90,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts(92,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts(93,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts(95,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts(96,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts(98,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts(99,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts(112,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts(114,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-ref.d.ts(55,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-ref.d.ts(57,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/overlay-ref.d.ts(63,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/position/connected-position-strategy.d.ts(36,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/position/connected-position-strategy.d.ts(40,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/position/connected-position-strategy.d.ts(43,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay/position/flexible-connected-position-strategy.d.ts(91,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/portal/portal-directives.d.ts(49,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/portal/portal-directives.d.ts(50,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/portal/portal-directives.d.ts(54,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/portal/portal.d.ts(24,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/portal/portal.d.ts(63,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/fixed-size-virtual-scroll.d.ts(75,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/fixed-size-virtual-scroll.d.ts(76,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/fixed-size-virtual-scroll.d.ts(82,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/fixed-size-virtual-scroll.d.ts(83,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/fixed-size-virtual-scroll.d.ts(88,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/fixed-size-virtual-scroll.d.ts(89,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/virtual-for-of.d.ts(49,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/virtual-for-of.d.ts(50,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/virtual-for-of.d.ts(56,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/virtual-for-of.d.ts(57,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/virtual-for-of.d.ts(60,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/virtual-scroll-viewport.d.ts(27,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/cdk/scrolling/virtual-scroll-viewport.d.ts(28,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/core/datetime/date-adapter.d.ts(29,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/core/option/option.d.ts(51,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/core/option/option.d.ts(53,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/core/option/option.d.ts(59,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/core/option/option.d.ts(60,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/core/option/option.d.ts(62,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/core/option/option.d.ts(74,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/core/option/option.d.ts(79,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/core/ripple/ripple.d.ts(60,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/core/ripple/ripple.d.ts(61,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/core/ripple/ripple.d.ts(67,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/core/ripple/ripple.d.ts(68,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/core/ripple/ripple.d.ts(85,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/core/ripple/ripple.d.ts(90,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/calendar.d.ts(30,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/calendar.d.ts(31,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/calendar.d.ts(33,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/calendar.d.ts(35,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/calendar.d.ts(69,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/calendar.d.ts(70,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/calendar.d.ts(75,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/calendar.d.ts(76,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/calendar.d.ts(79,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/calendar.d.ts(80,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/calendar.d.ts(83,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/calendar.d.ts(84,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/calendar.d.ts(114,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/calendar.d.ts(115,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/calendar.d.ts(118,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/calendar.d.ts(119,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker-input.d.ts(43,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker-input.d.ts(46,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker-input.d.ts(49,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker-input.d.ts(50,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker-input.d.ts(53,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker-input.d.ts(54,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker-input.d.ts(57,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker-input.d.ts(58,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker-input.d.ts(61,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker-input.d.ts(62,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker-toggle.d.ts(25,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker-toggle.d.ts(26,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker.d.ts(81,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker.d.ts(82,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker.d.ts(87,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker.d.ts(88,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker.d.ts(94,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker.d.ts(95,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker.d.ts(98,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker.d.ts(99,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker.d.ts(120,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker.d.ts(121,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker.d.ts(126,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker.d.ts(127,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker.d.ts(130,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker.d.ts(132,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/datepicker.d.ts(133,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/month-view.d.ts(25,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/month-view.d.ts(26,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/month-view.d.ts(29,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/month-view.d.ts(30,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/month-view.d.ts(33,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/month-view.d.ts(34,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/month-view.d.ts(37,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/month-view.d.ts(38,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/multi-year-view.d.ts(24,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/multi-year-view.d.ts(25,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/multi-year-view.d.ts(28,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/multi-year-view.d.ts(29,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/multi-year-view.d.ts(32,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/multi-year-view.d.ts(33,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/multi-year-view.d.ts(36,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/multi-year-view.d.ts(37,9):
>   error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/year-view.d.ts(23,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/year-view.d.ts(24,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/year-view.d.ts(27,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/year-view.d.ts(28,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/year-view.d.ts(31,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/year-view.d.ts(32,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/year-view.d.ts(35,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/year-view.d.ts(36,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/dialog.d.ts(46,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/dialog.d.ts(48,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/dialog.d.ts(49,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/form-field.d.ts(74,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/form-field.d.ts(75,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/form-field.d.ts(78,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/form-field.d.ts(79,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/form-field.d.ts(84,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/form-field.d.ts(86,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/form-field.d.ts(90,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/form-field.d.ts(91,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/form-field.d.ts(103,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/form-field.d.ts(104,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/form-field.d.ts(118,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/form-field.d.ts(119,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>       node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/form-field.d.ts(123,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

for package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular8-seed",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.1.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "github:angular/cdk-builds",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "8.0.0-beta.26",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "github:angular/material2-builds",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "latest",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.1",
    "angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.0.2",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^8.8.2",
    "angular-moment": "^1.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.4",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.20",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "mdb": "^0.1.0",
    "ng2-search-filter": "latest",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try updating typescript. npm i typescript@3.7.1 [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802463/types-sequelize-error-ts1086-an-accessor-cannot-be-declared-in-ambient-context][ts1086]

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to check version history and downgrade date-picker to older version, for example:

`npm i ng2-datepicker@2.3.1`

If it would not help try to deprecate typescript to older version.